# Making a UITextView work inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uistackview

I'm trying to add some UITextViews to a UIStackView and the text views aren't showing up. I've researched this issue and the #1 answer I found was to make `UITextViews.enableScrolling` set to `false`. However, when I do that, the text view becomes very long. It goes off the view controller and the UIStackView also becomes very wide and goes off beyond the edge of the view controller. Also (and this is true) all the other content in the UIStackView disappears. I think this is pretty strange.

This is a vertical stack view, by the way. I wish I better understood why the UIStackView was behaving this way. Any ideas on how to get the stack view to behave as expected would be most appreciated.  By the way, the UITextViews are not editable and don't have to respond to user interaction.  Below is the storyboard and the stack settings.

[image: View Controller] [image: Stack Settings]

At this point there are no constraints being used with the stack view or its contents.  I've updated the spacing between items to be 8, but that makes no difference- I've tried all numbers 0-8 and the UITextViews don't appear with any value.  Otherwise, I've basically left the UIStackView values alone.

Comment: what are your constraints on the stack view? this will effect everything inside of it

Comment: Can you show how your controller looks in the storyboard? And also what values did you set to the stackview parameters.

Comment: I've updated the contents to answer your questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but here's what I would suggest: Within the Stack View, you can explicitly set constraints for each object in the stack view. Try setting all the height constraints & width (using pin to sides, or explicit width) so that each object knows how to be distributed.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview:

> For all distributions except the fillEqually distribution, 
>   the stack view uses each arranged view’s `intrinsicContentSize` 
>   property when calculating its size along the stack’s axis.